# Remove object from document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

If the var `author` is set, I do an update to the mongoDB document to insert a new object `{ assignTo: author }`. If it is already existing, it will be updated.

But if `author` is empty, I would like to remove the `assignTo` from the document. How do I do that?

```
if (author) {
    Collection.update(
        { _id: id }, 
        { $set: { assignTo: author } }
    );  
}   
else {
    // remove object from collection
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$unset` to remove the `assignTo` field from the document:

```
else {
 Collection.update(
  { _id: id }, 
  { $unset: { assignTo: "" } }
 );  
}
```